# How to get a list of groups and group memberships in Azure?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, azure, entra-id

How can I get a list of all the groups and undergroups that a user is member of?
Or how can I search for a specific undergroup? Nayone who knows of a command for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure AD PowerShell module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) to get users and groups programmatically. This would allow you to write a query to get a user, and then list any groups a user is in.

For example:

```
Get-AzureADUser -SearchString user@domain.com | Get-AzureADUserMembership
```